# Batch + files + day of the year

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

As a complete newbie when it comes to Batch coding i would like to know the most easy way to achive the following. Inside a (windows 7 system) i have a folder and inside that folder a couple of .mp3 files with the filenames sample001.mp3 -> sample366.mp3

What i would like to do is find the sample(day-of-the-year-number).mp3 and move this to another location on this windows 7 system and in the same move rename it to just sample.mp3 how could i do this with as little code as possible to be lightweight and will run daily.

kind regards,
Patrik!

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that this is not a script writing service, the solution to this is easier written in the answer area than in the comments.

You could use [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) for this task, as it has built-in support for dates. However, to stay on topic with your question tags, you can still leverage it from a single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```batch-file
@For /F %%G In ('^""%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile "(Get-Date).DayOfYear"^"')Do @Move /Y "Sample%%G.mp3" 'NewLocation\Sample.mp3"
```

*Just include the target location if necessary and replace "NewLocation" as needed*